# RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition() showing inconsistent behaviour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with each row consisting of a horizontal and a vertical RecyclerView. The height of the vertical RecyclerView is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` so it is not scrollable and shows all its items.

The top-level RecyclerView, thus has rows with variable height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/available_rooms_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/date_view_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/room_type"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            tools:text="Oak Availability" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/available_rooms_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/all_guests_recycler"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works perfectly, except one thing, `smoothScrollToPosition()`. When I want to smooth scroll to the top of any row in the top-level RecyclerView, the scroll occurs, but to wrong positions (not exactly where it should have been).

What is the problem here and how can it be solved?

Comment: where its scrolling ?

Comment: To the position mentioned by on at the top of the view. Sometimes a bit below it, and sometimes a bit above the top of the view.